# Random background color in a loop (Java)

Tags: java

I want to change the background color of a panel each time repaint() is called. I'm having a hard time doing it with setBackground, so I wonder if a drawRect with the same dimensions as the frame will do the same job, or is this a no-no?

```
public class Artwork extends JPanel implements Runnable {

boolean running = false;
Random rng = new Random();

public Artwork() {
    this.setOpaque(true);
}

public void Start() {
    running = true;
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public void Stop() {
    running = false;
}

public void run() {
    while (running = true) {
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    super.setBackground(randomColor());
}

public Color randomColor() {
    int r = rng.nextInt(255);
    int g = rng.nextInt(255);
    int b = rng.nextInt(255);
    return new Color(r, g, b);
}
```

With this the background color changes rapidly regardless of Thread.sleep

Comment: Needs code.  `setBackground()` always worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With this the background color changes rapidly regardless of Thread.sleep

Painting methods are for painting only!

Don't invoke methods (like `setBackground()`) that change the property of the component in the paintComponent() method. Swing components automatically repaint() themselves when a property is changed. This will cause an infinite loop as the component repaints itself again and again and again....

The solution is to invoke the `setBackground()` method in the Thread before invoking the repaint method.

Comment: Setting the background in the run method itself worked great. Thanks!